# Gridview on postback or way to serialize it

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.net web site and several pages with grid views.  And, the grid views get feed from DataTable objects.  Upon postback, in order to repopulate the grid views without having to access database, I store them in session variables.  My questions are:

1. How would you normally handle this in case of postback and you don’t want to access database again?
2. It seems like I need to serialize the DataTable object, how do I do this?  My initial thought was that DataTable is already serializable, but I guess not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Caching, serialization is not used and you should have no problems.